# Python - JSON results with nested for loops

Tags: python, json, spotify, nested-loops

Nested `for loops` alongside `JSON`results can be mind bending.

With the code below I would like to fetch `track names` which belong to a specific `playlist`.

I create a series of empty lists:

```
#for 'search' endpoint results
owner_ids = []
playlist_query_names = []
playlist_query_ids = []

#for 'playlist' endpoint results
playlist_names = []
track_names = []
track_ids = []
```

then a `function` to perform a `query`:

```
def query_playlists(query):

    #query 'search' endpoint(desired playlists),
    #with no track_ids to be found
    query_results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')

    query_items = query_results['playlists']['items']

    for item in query_items:
        playlist_query_names.append(item['name'])
        playlist_query_ids.append(item['id'])
        owner = item['owner']
        owner_ids.append(owner['id'])
```

however, one must access another `endpoint` in order to retrieve `track names`:

```
    #lookup 'user_playlists' endpoint (all playlists),
    #where track ids are to be found
    playlist_results = [sp.user_playlists(owner) for owner in owner_ids]
    playlist_items = playlist_results[0]['items']

    for item in playlist_items:
        playlist_name =  item['name']
        playlist_names.append(playlist_name)
        username = item['owner']['id']
```

here is the method for the other `endpoint`

```
        results = sp.user_playlist(username, item['id'], fields="tracks,next")

        #intersect both endpoints         
        if playlist_name in playlist_query_names:
            tracks = results['tracks']

            #find desired tracks
            for item in (tracks['items']):
                track = item['track']
                track_id = item['track']['uri']
                #add tracks
                track_names.append(track['name'])
                track_ids.append(track_id)
    return track_ids, track_names
```

somehow I'm not being able to narrow down `track names` `results` to `playlists` obtained via `search` `endpoint`

could please some rigorous mind point me out where my mistake is?

**EDIT**

`JSON`results from `playlists` `endpoint`:

`[{u'items': [{u'is_local': False, u'track': {u'album': {u'album_type': u'album', u'name': u'At Last!', u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/album/2pBhXw3Hi1hBf8FpAtE101'}, u'uri': u'spotify:album:2pBhXw3Hi1hBf8FpAtE101', u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2pBhXw3Hi1hBf8FpAtE101', u'images': [{u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/6387bb37eb021db9f3c9da7173fd093f5ded2429', u'width': 640, u'height': 637}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/55d6dc87cf5f29485c251cf672a0896bd87cc2b9', u'width': 300, u'height': 299}, {u'url': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/8bcfde39549a94c46e9cf51e653572a71aaf1f0d', u'width': 64, u'height': 64}], u'type': u'album', u'id': u'2pBhXw3Hi1hBf8FpAtE101', u'available_markets': [u'AD'..., u'UY']}, u'name': u'At Last - Single Version', u'uri': u'spotify:track:0CmIALzGn4vHIHJG4n3Q4z', u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/track/0CmIALzGn4vHIHJG4n3Q4z'}, u'popularity': 65, u'explicit': False, u'preview_url': u'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/a8fc45fd24d3f6aaaa33262cba0d5c91b37d56fd', u'track_number': 7, u'disc_number': 1, u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0CmIALzGn4vHIHJG4n3Q4z', u'artists': [{u'name': u'Etta James', u'external_urls': {u'spotify': u'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0iOVhN3tnSvgDbcg25JoJb'}, u'uri': u'spotify:artist:0iOVhN3tnSvgDbcg25JoJb', u'href': u'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0iOVhN3tnSvgDbcg25JoJb', u'type': u'artist', u'id': u'0iOVhN3tnSvgDbcg25JoJb'}], u'duration_ms': 182400, u'external_ids': {u'isrc': u'USMC16046323'}, u'type': u'track', u'id': u'0CmIALzGn4vHIHJG4n3Q4z', u'available_markets': [u'AD',...u'UY']}, u'added_by': None, u'added_at': u'2012-01-06T10:47:09Z'}, {u'is_local': False...]`

Comment: Well, your first mistake is using a bunch of global variables

Comment: Can you please also share your sample JSON structure?

Comment: Your question is receiving "close" votes because it doesn't meet the requirements of [mcve].

Comment: Please add it with question. In comment, the content is getting truncated to exceeding of max char limit

Comment: @GreenAsJade unfortunately, I've been trying for days to post questions with short snippets to no avail.

Comment: @NullUserException ok, but that does not seem to be critical

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri do you need anything else?

Comment: Check last line `[u'AD',...u'UY']}, u'added_by': None, u'added_at': u'2012-01-06T10:47:09Z'}...]`. There are `...`, means still your JSON is not complete

Comment: There is no need to add the complete JSON, just the format which will help us to verify the code

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, please note by the edit `{u'is_local': False...` that the data structure is complete as it is, and it will start repeating its pattern from then on

Comment: @data_garden It isn't critical, but it makes your code much harder to test and debug

Comment: @NullUser Exception you are right, I've corrected the code, thank you for pointing out. what I meant is that is not where the real problem lies.